# Is there any performance difference between a shallow/wide database and a deep/skinny one?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Say you have a database where you wish to store stock chart data consisting of a series of "candles".  "Candles" have five properties - `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, and `Timestamp`.

I'm currently storing them as a `|`-delimited string and I have one table `Stocks` consisting of two columns:

`PK (AAPL)`

`TickData (big string)`

I fetch the raw string `TickData` and parse it serverside into in-memory objects, and then send that over to the browser.  The rows here would be very fat, but the tables would be shallow.

The alternative is a table of `Stocks` with a one to many relationship with another table of `Ticks` or `Candles` but that table would become very, very deep and skinny.

Should I expect to see any significant performance impact (or enhancement) by using something like an ORM + mature schema to do it "the right way" - deep, skinny, and denormalized?

Comment: I wouldn't call this *database design*, looks like a flat file, if you only display all data for a single stock it might be possble. But what's the time granularity for storing your data, hours, minutes, seconds and the range you want to store, weeks, months, years? This might result in millions of "candles", how will you search for specific properties? Btw, for stock ticker data there are specialized *time series* databases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing work in the application that should really be done in the database.  There are some advantages to your approach.  For instance:

- The data is smaller, because things like stock codes are not stored repeatedly.
- If you need all the data for a given stock, you can readily fetch it.

The data is only useful for the application that knows how to parse it.  That makes the data much less useful than it otherwise could be.

This approach misses a bunch of things that databases do:

- You cannot validate the data.
- You are storing numeric and datetime data as strings.
- The SQL engine cannot optimize the query, except for an index on the stock code (which might be sufficient).
- It is less scalable than you might imagine -- the strings just get bigger over time.
- Inserting new data is expensive, because you have to copy increasing large strings.
- Updating/deleting data is expensive and complicated.
- You cannot retrieve only part of the data.

I strongly recommend that you have a "candles" table, with  what looks like (at least) six columns each of the appropriate data type.